# jackson serializer cover String null to empty String("") and keep object null is null

Tags: string, dictionary, null, jackson, serialization

I have tried several ways

e.g.

1.create a custom JsonSerializer, and override serialize method

```
 @Override
 public void serialize(Object value, JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider serializers) throws IOException {
    gen.writeString("");
}
```

and set the JsonSerializer to NullValueSerializer,like this:

```
objectMapper.getSerializerProvider().setNullValueSerializer(new NullStringSerializer());
```

but we can not get the Class Type from null. All null will be covert to "" , include the object.

2.if use SimpleModule

```
 SimpleModule simpleModule = new SimpleModule("StringModule", Version.unknownVersion());
 simpleModule.addSerializer(Object.class, new NullStringSerializer());
 objectMapper.registerModule(simpleModule);
```

in the serialize method, the param value do not have any properties which is null.

from the resouce code of jackson 2.6.0 , find method `serializeFields`  in MapSerializer.java (my object is a map) line: 545

```
 for (Map.Entry<?,?> entry : value.entrySet()) {
            Object valueElem = entry.getValue();
            // First, serialize key
            Object keyElem = entry.getKey();
            if (keyElem == null) {
                provider.findNullKeySerializer(_keyType, _property).serialize(null, gen, provider);
            } else {
                // One twist: is entry ignorable? If so, skip
                if (ignored != null && ignored.contains(keyElem)) continue;
                keySerializer.serialize(keyElem, gen, provider);
            }

            // And then value
            if (valueElem == null) {
                provider.defaultSerializeNull(gen);
            } else {...}
}
```

when the valueElem is null, the provide just covert it to null.
and do not have any interface for me to change the strategy.

I can override MapSerializer ,but I do not know how to set the new MapSerializer to the factory.

Is there any solution?

expect your help,thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

find a solution :
the abstract class `SerializerProvider` has a method named `findNullValueSerializer`, which is called to get the serializer to use for serializing null values for specified property.
We can override `SerializerProvider#findNullValueSerializer` and match String class:

```
@Override
public JsonSerializer<Object> findNullValueSerializer(BeanProperty property) throws JsonMappingException {
    if (property.getType().getRawClass().equals(String.class)) {
        return EmptyStringSerializer.INSTANCE;
    } else {
        return super.findNullValueSerializer(property);
    }
}
```

and then set SerializerProvider to our ObjectMapper instance.

done.