# Change JSON value from null to empty String

Tags: java, spring-boot, jackson

im making a rest controller which return json. i get this data from database, mapping in to java class using setter getter.

```
{
  "example": null,
  "this": null,
  "is": null,
  "only": null,
  "example": null,
  "foo": null,
  "bar": null,
  "blabla": null,
  "lala": null
}
```

its because the data in database not present. but i want the data to be like this:

```
{
      "example": ""    ,
      "this": "",
      "is": "",
      "only": "",
      "example": "",
      "foo": "",
      "bar": "",
      "blabla": "",
      "lala": ""
 }
```

i have more than 100 fields. so i think its not good to use if else in every variable.

Comment: How are you deserializing the json? Can you add that logic there?

Comment: Lookup this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38071243/jackson-serializer-cover-string-null-to-empty-string-and-keep-object-null-is

Comment: @TomerShetah im using ObjectMapper.valueToTree, it still get null. im using class and then return to controller still get null too.

Answer (score 2):

You can override default `ObjectMapper` (provided by Spring Boot auto-configuration) and configure globally format to use for properties of type `String`.

```java
@Configuration
public class JacksonConfiguration {

    @Bean
    ObjectMapper jacksonObjectMapper(Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder builder) {
        final var objectMapper = builder.createXmlMapper(false).build();
        objectMapper.configOverride(String.class).setSetterInfo(JsonSetter.Value.forValueNulls(Nulls.AS_EMPTY));
        return objectMapper;
    }

}
```

Comment: is var in java8 equals object?

Comment: `var` can be used in a local variable declaration instead of the variable's type. It's available since Java 10. 
Java 8 equivalent syntax is - `final ObjectMapper objectMapper = ...`

Comment: it still get null if the data in db not present.

Comment: make sure you injected `ObjectMapper` configured by Spring into your controller.

Comment: @Autowired private ObjectMapper mapper; and then JsonNode tes = mapper.valueToTree(result); still get null

Answer (score 0):

```
DefaultSerializerProvider.Impl sp = new DefaultSerializerProvider.Impl();
sp.setNullValueSerializer(new NullSerializer());
new ObjectMapper().setSerializerProvider(sp)...
```

Where

```
public class NullSerializer extends JsonSerializer<Object> {
    @Override
    public void serialize(Object o, JsonGenerator jsonGenerator, SerializerProvider serializerProvider) throws IOException {
        jsonGenerator.writeString("");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can solve it more easily by handling json string:

```
jsonString = jsonString.replaceAll("null,", "'',");
```